# When will official NDK support be added to Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

Is there anyone who knows when NDK will be added to android studio? Of course there are some ways to add NDK to android studio but they are not official.

Comment: This issue might be of interest to you: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82187

Comment: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/   official or no, its working for ndk projects

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** : NDK support in Android-Studio will be available in version 1.3. The preview is now available as an update patch on the canary channel.

[Here is the annoucement](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/05/android-m-developer-preview-tools.html)

---

Here is the canonical feature request regarding ndk support in Android Studio:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55331

The ["roadmap" for android tools](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/roadmap) mention that the *NDK integration* is currently planned after gradle 1.0... and gradle-plugin for Android 1.0 is out now.

As far as I know Google never communicates any release date for this feature (and it has never been a Google's habit to communicate a release date for anything either)

To answer your question : "so far, nobody knows."